# Wordpress and Custom PHP single SignOn

Tags: php

I have a Wordpress installation and some php pages (not related to Wordpress). I want to use the same login between Wordpress and My Php pages. When I login from my php, and go to wordpress, it shouldn't prompt me to login again (and vice versa). Can you please tell me how to do this? Thank you.

Comment: How do you manage the users on your PHP pages?

Comment: Users are only in wordpress database. I want to reuse the wordrpess database for logging into my php pages. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can integrate the wordpress authentication with the apache webserver and then configure which additional resources need a login on your webserver. This works with PHP as well with HTML and images.

For more information, please see [mod_auth_mysql and phpass](http://barry.wordpress.com/2008/05/19/mod_auth_mysql-and-phpass/).